# How to Change hidden (+delay) node to Primary node in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

**Problem Statement:**

Need to promote Hidden node which is delayed node (30 mins) too to Primary node. I want to test this delayed node feature in case of primary/secondary data corrupt.

I have a test environment with 4 node replica set:

> 10.0.0.1 - Hidden Delay node (30 mins)
>
> 10.0.0.2 - Primary Node
>
> 10.0.0.3 - Secondary Node
>
> 10.0.0.4 - Hidden Delay node (1 hour)

Below are the steps that I tried:

1. With a simple script add some data into the primary & checked it on hidden node whether new data is present or not. Data was not there till the next 30 mins.
2. Stopped Primary node 10.0.0.2 & 10.0.0.3 became Primary then.
3. The issue below command to promote Hidden as Primary.

   ```
   cfg = rs.conf()
   cfg.members[0].hidden = false
   cfg.members[0].priority = 1
   rs.reconfig(cfg, {force : true})
   rs.reconfig(cfg)
   ```
4. In the above command, I'm missing the slave delay to use. Not sure what is the correct method to promote this node as Primary.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Include the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.